# How to match a vue-router route and use it in a component function

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Using the `vue-router` package, it is easy to [match dynamic segments](http://router.vuejs.org/en/route.html):

```
router.map({
  '/user/:username': {
    component: {
      template: '<p>username is {{$route.params.username}}</p>'
    }
   }
})
```

However, I couldn't figure out how to use the value a component method, e.g.

```
router.map({
  '/user/:username': {
    component: {
      ready: function() {
         // How to access the param here?
         alert($route.params.username);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

How can I access the matched segment in the component method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is almost as what you posted

```
// inside your component
this.$route.params.username
```

The key is that in the template you don't need to refer to the `this` scope, but in methods you have to use it

Comment: Easy, I could have guessed that. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The `$route` object is injected in every router maped compeonents , as per your case you would use the `params` method to get the key/value passed .

```
router.map({
  '/user/:username': {
    component: {
      ready: function() {
         // How to access the param 
        // use the scope 'this'
         alert(this.$route.params.username);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

for more info check out http://router.vuejs.org/en/api/route-object.html